# SQL PHP form error on line 23

Tags: php, html, sql

I have been trying to write code to insert into different tables but it keeps giving me error on line 23.

This is for a college project registration form.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect(","","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("HNDGeorgeMason", $con);

$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
$userid=$_POST['userid'];
$type=$_POST['type'];

switch ($_POST['type'])
{
case guides
 $sql="INSERT INTO Guides (firstname, surname, type, username, password)
 VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$type', '$username', '$password')";

case parents
 $sql="INSERT INTO Parents (firstname, surn ame, type, username, password)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$type', '$username', '$password')"; 

case leaders
 $sql="INSERT INTO Leaders (firstname, surname, type, username, password)
 VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$type', '$username', '$password')"; 
}

 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/taxiedin/public_html/oban/php/reg.php on line 23

Comment: also check your case parents there may be surname in place of surn ame.

Comment: thanks for that, cheers guys for all the answers, did not realise I would get a reply so quickly many thanks

Comment: @georgemason Please accept an answer if you feel you have found what you needed. Thanks.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Check your code at

- `$con = mysql_connect(","","");`
- In cases: eg: `case "guides"`
- NEVER EVER just insert your $_POST without sanitizing the input (due to [SQL Injection)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). use atleast [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I edited connection information out

Comment: @georgemason . Ok but you had a missing open quote there.

Comment: its a really basic script, just trying to get it working for college

Comment: @georgemason But It will break your code if you encounter a special charecter of SQL like `"` in you `address` field for example

Comment: thanks for the info, I havent dealt with sanitizing yet but can you recommend som good places to read ?

Comment: @georgemason if you are interested in digging deeper into the security aspects of programming goto owasp.org and look up the top 10 list. If you are a casual programmer then look into SQL Injection and XSS attacks. Tutorials are available. I suggest you use a plugin to counter XSS as its very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
case "leaders":
 $sql="INSERT INTO Leaders (firstname, surname, type, username, password)
 VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$type', '$username', '$password')"; 
break;
```

Comment: Does it need the colon at the end ?